# Before I install Ubuntu, I want to be sure that there are wireless drivers for my card. Where do I go to find these drivers?

Tags: drivers

I've had problems in the past with LInux distributions not having drivers for my hardware. HOw can I be sure that I will find drivers for my current machine and all of its components?

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 (3541)(Mid 2014) Service Tag J1Q2312. I have been to the Dell support site and looked and used the drivers there and did not see anything that supported Linux.

Where would I find Linux drivers for my components?

Comment: Try running Ubuntu in Live boot mode through a cd/usb drive. If the network works here, it would work when OS is installed.

Comment: Which wireless is build in? you can check this either by looking at your system or checking online via dell

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question "Which wireless is 'build' in? What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to provide a little bit of info here.

A lot of manufacturers (Dell included) do not provide Linux drivers because they usually do not have them.  As well, a lot of drivers are readily available through a Google search.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to say where one should go for a driver, as we do NOT have your entire hardware list.  To that end, you should run Ubuntu in a Live environment (LiveCD or LiveUSB) and test things.  It would be able to determine whether you'd need additional drivers or not.

Answer (score 1):

often it is easier to just buy a supported WiFi card or use a USB dongle than to waste days trying to get some vendors products to work.  You can get a new Intel dual link AC card for under $30.  Well worth every penny if you have ever tried to get some vendor (ahem br*dc*m)

Comment: This is for a laptop. I am not sure I want to mess with the parts in there.